# Matrix dot product

Tags: c++, cuda

Disclaimer: Im a cuda beginner.

```
typedef struct
{
    int row_;
    int col_;
    float* element_;
    int step;
}Matrix_t;

#define BLOCK_SIZE 64

__device__ float getElement(const Matrix_t A, int row, int col);
__device__ Matrix_t getSubMat(Matrix_t A, int row, int col);
__device__ void setElement(Matrix_t A, int row, int col, float value);
__global__ void MatrixDot(Matrix_t A, Matrix_t B, float* dot_);
float  Matrix_dot_(float* M_dev_1, float* M_dev_2, int Number_of_cols, int Number_of_rows, int step);
```

the Matrix_t are used to link a cv::cuda::GpuMat to the C interface via the ptr() operator to get the GPU pointer to element.

```
__device__ float getElement(const Matrix_t A, int row, int col)
{
    return A.element_[row* A.step + col];
}

__device__ void setElement(Matrix_t A, int row, int col, float value)
{
    A.element_[row*A.step + col] = value;
}
__device__ Matrix_t getSubMat(Matrix_t A, int row, int col)
{
    Matrix_t A_sub;
    A_sub.row_ = BLOCK_SIZE;
    A_sub.col_ = BLOCK_SIZE;
    A_sub.step = A.step;
    A_sub.element_ = &A.element_[A.step * BLOCK_SIZE * row + BLOCK_SIZE * col];

    return A_sub;
}
```

Here is the kernel:

```
__global__ void MatrixDot(Matrix_t A, Matrix_t B, float* dot_)
{
    int blockRow = blockIdx.y;
    int blockCol = blockIdx.x;


    float SubDotValue = 0.0f;


    int row = threadIdx.y;
    int col = threadIdx.x;



    for(int m = 0; m < (A.row_ / BLOCK_SIZE); ++m)
    {
        //get subA & subB
        Matrix_t A_sub = getSubMat(A, blockRow, m);
        Matrix_t B_sub = getSubMat(B, blockRow, m);

        //set Asub & Bsub to the  __shared__ memory

        __shared__ float ASub[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
        __shared__ float BSub[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

        ASub[row][col] = getElement(A_sub, row, col);
        BSub[row][col] = getElement(B_sub, row, col);

        //Synchronize before calculations:
        __syncthreads();

        //Get the dot product of the vector Asub[] Bsub[]
        for(int el_ = 0; el_ < BLOCK_SIZE; ++el_)
        {
            SubDotValue += ASub[row][el_] * BSub[row][el_];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

    dot_[row] = SubDotValue;

}
```

and the wrapper:

```
float  Matrix_dot_(float* M_dev_1,float* M_dev_2, int Number_of_cols, int Number_of_rows, int step)
{


    float retval = 0;
    float* retval_partial;
    float* retval_device;

    Matrix_t A;
    A.col_ = Number_of_cols;
    A.row_ = Number_of_rows;
    A.element_ = M_dev_1;
    A.step = step;
    Matrix_t B;
    B.col_ = Number_of_cols;
    B.row_ = Number_of_rows;
    B.element_ = M_dev_2;
    B.step = step;



    retval_partial = (float*)malloc( B.row_*sizeof(float) );

    cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc( (void**)&retval_device,B.row_/ BLOCK_SIZE *sizeof(float) );
    printf("\n Cuda malloc: %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    std::cout<<std::flush;
    dim3 dimBlock(BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 dimGrid(B.row_ / BLOCK_SIZE, B.col_ / BLOCK_SIZE);

    MatrixDot<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(A, B, retval_device);
    err = cudaThreadSynchronize();
    std::cout<<std::flush;

    printf("\n Cuda kernel run: %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    err = cudaMemcpy(retval_partial, retval_device, B.row_ / BLOCK_SIZE* sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("\n Cuda cudaMemcpy: %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    err = cudaFree(retval_device);
    printf("\n Cuda cudaFree: %s", cudaGetErrorString(err));
    for(int i = 0; i<B.row_/ BLOCK_SIZE ; ++i)
    {
        retval+=retval_partial[i];
    }

    free(retval_partial);

    return retval;
}
```

and the main:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cv::cuda::DeviceInfo devInfo;
    cv::cuda::setDevice(devInfo.deviceID());

    cv::Mat cudatestA = cv::Mat(64*3, 64*3, CV_32FC1, 2);
    cv::Mat cudatestB = cv::Mat(64*3, 64*3, CV_32FC1, 2);


    double tr = (double) cv::getTickCount();
    double res = cudatestA.dot(cudatestB);

    tr = ((double)cv::getTickCount()-tr)/(double)cv::getTickFrequency();

    cv::cuda::GpuMat ctA(cudatestA);
    cv::cuda::GpuMat ctB(cudatestB);


    double tm_ = (double) cv::getTickCount();
    float res_m = 0;

    res_m = Matrix_dot_((float* )ctA.ptr(), (float*)ctB.ptr(), ctA.cols, ctA.rows, ctA.step);
    tm_ = ((double)cv::getTickCount()-tm_)/(double)cv::getTickFrequency();


    printf("\nCPU: %0.4fms, res: %0.4f\nGPU_M: %0.4fms, res: %0.4f\n", tr*1000.0f, res, tm_*1000.0f,res_m);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm currently stuck on various points:

1) it always output 0.

2) it can only work for matrix M*N Multiple of the defined BLOCK_SIZE (64).

for 1) I can't figure where my logic break, I could get the dot product to work on vector without any troubles but the matrix problem induced by the stride between each row prevent me to use the code (code deleted as the site tell me that there is too much code).

Comment: Hints: Invalid block size (maximum 1024 threads per block are allowed), matrix step should be divided by the size of data-type, i.e. `step/sizeof(float)`.

Comment: @sgarizvi I assumed that GpuMat.step would return an int.... I was wrong, I'll test tomorrow morning. Any hints/other things that might be wrong? (also is there a debugger for CUDA except gdb?)

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

In your kernel you aren't doing the good sum, nor taking the good elements, and your dim seems inverted

```
__global__ void MatrixDot(Matrix_t A, Matrix_t B, float* dot_)
{
//int blockRow = blockIdx.y;
//int blockCol = blockIdx.x;
int blockRow = blockIdx.x;
int blockCol = blockIdx.y;


float SubDotValue = 0.0f;


//int row = threadIdx.y;
//int col = threadIdx.x;
int row = threadIdx.x;
int col = threadIdx.y;




for(int m = 0; m < (A.row_ / BLOCK_SIZE); ++m)
    {
        //get subA & subB
        Matrix_t A_sub = getSubMat(A, m, blockCol);//getSubMat(A, blockRow, m)
        Matrix_t B_sub = getSubMat(B, m, blockCol);//getSubMat(B, blockRow, m)

        //set Asub & Bsub to the  __shared__ memory

        __shared__ float ASub[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];
        __shared__ float BSub[BLOCK_SIZE][BLOCK_SIZE];

        ASub[row][col] = getElement(A_sub, row, col);
        BSub[row][col] = getElement(B_sub, row, col);

        //Synchronize before calculations:
        __syncthreads();

        //Get the dot product of the vector Asub[] Bsub[]
        for(int el_ = 0; el_ < BLOCK_SIZE; ++el_)
        {
            SubDotValue += ASub[row][el_] * BSub[row][el_];
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }

dot_[blockRow*BLOCK_SIZE + row] = SubDotValue; //dot_[row] = SubDotValue;

}
```

And your wrapper isn't also allocating the size you need:

```
cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc( (void**)&retval_device,B.row_/ BLOCK_SIZE *sizeof(float) );
```

should be:

```
cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc( (void**)&retval_device,B.row_*sizeof(float) );
```

Note that other allocation related have to change too (Lazy me).

And your call in main need to divide the GpuMat step by the size of one element of the GpuMat

```
res_m = Matrix_dot_((float* )ctA.ptr(), (float*)ctB.ptr(), ctA.cols, ctA.rows, ctA.step/ctA.elemsize1());
```

You might also want to change your Matrix_t structure to use const float* instead of float to be able to use:

```
 GpuMat_.ptr<float>();
```

instead of:

```
(float*)GpuMat.ptr();
```

Note that for a matrix of N rows you are starting N^2 threads doing the same thing. I don't have enough knowledge on Cuda to fix that.